# Connect to remote SQL Server failed using pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to MS SQL Server through Ubuntu. I configured the connection the server on windows and the connection works there:

```
import pyodbc
conn_str = f"Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server={SERVER_NAME};Database={DB_NAME};Trusted_Connection={yes};"
```

However, when I use the same credentials in my Ubuntu environment on the same machine, I am met with this error:
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I have tried to implement many things. I have set the server to allow remote connections, enabled TCP/IP connections and bypassed windows firewall settings by creating inbound rules. I have installed the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and made an obdc.ini file.

I am quite lost on how to proceed. Do I specify the port number on the SERVER_NAME? Do I use an IP address instead of the name of the server? Is this an issue due to windows authentication?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Trusted_Connection` means that the connection is meant to be using the Active Directory/Kerberos/Windows authentication token of the currently running process. Do your firewalls permit these authentication processes, or only the port that the SQL Server instance is listening on? Is the Ubuntu machine joined to the domain with Kerberos?

Comment: Is there a way to verify to verify these permissions or check if my ubuntu machine is connected with Kerberos?

Comment: If `klist` doesn't return information about your ticket cache or default principal, or the `klist` command is not found, then your Ubuntu machine doesn't have Kerberos installed and configured and it's not joined to any domain.